# Looping through a few files and analyzing each

Tags: loops, csv, spss

I want to do some tests on several csv file with SPSS. My problem here, is that i want to :
open a file -> do my test -> report -> and so on
Right now everything works when I play the prog for one file, so i want to pass to the next step.
for now i've got a code like this one :

```
DATA LIST FREE/ directory (A100) file (A100) type (A10).
BEGIN DATA
    C:\Users\Olivier\Desktop\Zebrys\data\ integ_ narr   
END DATA.
compute file=concat(directory,"integ_").
EXECUTE.
compute file=concat(file,type).
EXECUTE.
compute file=concat(file,"_1_unif_tiny_1.csv").
EXECUTE.
compute file=concat("'",file,"'").
EXECUTE.


GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE=file
  /ENCODING='UTF8
....'
```

the part which doesn't works it's when i use the variable "file" it doesn't recognize it.
In the end i want to put this code into a loop. 
Maybe I have a clever way to do so ?

Comment: See my answer below, but also a helpful tip: When calculating the file name you could get the same results in one line like this: `compute file=concat("'", directory, "integ_", type, "_1_unif_tiny_1.csv" ,"'").` . Note also that in any case you don't need an EXECUTE after every syntax line (sometimes not at all - look it up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've defined the variable name and path as you have, you can put it into syntax using the `write` command, which will create a new syntax with an edited command in it - which you can then `insert`.

To continue the example in your post, you could continue like this:

```
write out="somepath\open my data.sps" 
      /"GET DATA /TYPE=TXT /FILE=", file," /ENCODING='UTF8' ...  ." .
insert file="somepath\open my data.sps" .
```

The above syntax will open the file, as defined.
This is of course a good basis to loop through a few files - a `get data` command will be created for each line in the present data. If you use your `data list` command to create a few file names, they will all be opened.
Now what you want to do is also add some analyses after each file is opened. You can do that by adding lines to the created syntax after each `get data` command:

```
write out="somepath\open my data.sps" 
      /"GET DATA /TYPE=TXT /FILE=", file," /ENCODING='UTF8' ...  ." 
      /"dataset name newdata."
      /"freq var1 to var30".
      /"dataset close newdata." .
insert file="somepath\open my data.sps" .
```

Now if you had a few names defined in the data (in the `file` variable) the inserted syntax will open each one of them in it's turn and run the three extra commands on it.